# How is the decryption key of a bitlocker encrypted drive generated?

Tags: bitlocker

A laptop from a company is in a domain and gets Bitlocker encrypted. When the SSD of this laptop gets placed into another the drive is locked because the hardware changed. It asks for an unlock key by providing a Key ID.

Will this be the unlock key of the original laptop or the new laptop? If it is the original laptop does that mean the whole old laptop gets encrypted and its ID is stored on the SSD? If the SSD is placed in two different laptops will the decryption key still be the same?

Answer (score 1):

> How is the decryption key of a bitlocker encrypted drive generated?

The master key is randomly generated, and never shown to the user.

If you run `manage-bde -status` or `manage-bde c: -protectors -get`, you'll see that each disk can have multiple so-called "protectors", each of which holds its own copy of the disk's master key. In most cases, there are two:

1. the first copy is sealed using the old laptop's TPM chip;
2. the second copy is encrypted using a randomly-generated 48-digit "recovery password" that Windows usually asks to write down or print out.

> Will this be the unlock key of the original laptop or the new laptop?

Neither. This is an *alternate* key stored within the BitLocker metadata itself – it is randomly generated and not related to the system's hardware in any way. (This is in fact *the whole point* of the recovery key – you can always use it no matter what hardware has changed.)

> If it is the original laptop does that mean the whole old laptop gets encrypted and its ID is stored on the SSD?

The "key ID" is completely unrelated to the laptop nor the physical disk; it's just a completely random ID that acts like a "name" for the numeric unlock password / recovery key. (For example, if you manage a large office and have 100 recovery keys written down, the "key ID" lets you know what computer needs what key.)

> If the SSD is placed in two different laptops will the decryption key still be the same?

Yes – the master key is always the same, and all non-hardware protectors (password, or .bek key on USB stick, or numeric recovery key) will be the same unless you deliberately change them.

However, BitLocker can only store one TPM protector, so you can only have automatic unlock happening on one laptop. Every time you move the disk to a new laptop, it will ask you for the recovery key first.

Comment: Thank you, one additional question: If a laptop is encrypted, its master key is stored in TPM and an alternate key is generated, right? If the SSD of this laptop is then placed in another laptop with TPM, can it be decrypted with the TPM key only, not the alternate key? Which TPM key would it be, the first laptop TPM key or the second?

Comment: All keys (protectors) can equally decrypt the master key. If you have the numeric "recovery key", that's enough – the TPM key is not needed.

Comment: The key is stored in the TPM of the first machine.  The only way to decrypt the data on the second machine is with the recovery key.  In fact just by attempting to boot to the BitLocker protected device will require the recovery key no matter what device you use the next time you attempt to boot to the BitLocker protected drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrypt the Bitlocker disk on the new computer exactly as on the old computer:

- When inserting a BitLocker-encrypted drive to another Windows 10 computer,
  a message in the lower right corner of the desktop will say:

  [image]
- Click on this message for displaying the password dialog with it you can unlock
  the drive:

  [image]
- If you forgot/lost the password to unlock this drive, click "More options"
  followed by "Enter recovery key" and then enter the 48-digit recovery key
  to unlock this drive.

If you don't have any of the above two keys, the situation becomes complicated
or impossible.